# Arrow function in javascript's replace function

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a very simple code that converts every letter to lower case and later sets upper case for every first letter using RegExp:

```
let quote = 'I dO nOT lIke gREen eGgS anD HAM';
let fixQuote = quote.toLocaleLowerCase('en-US');

let regex = /(^\w|\s\w)/g;

let fixedQuote = fixQuote.replace(regex, m => m.toUpperCase());
```

Can someone explain what does the arrow function `m => m.` does in this part?
I don't understand what `m` stands for here.

Thanks!

Comment: It replaces every match with its uppercase equivalent.

Comment: It is explained in the [String#replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) docs

Comment: it's like this `function f(m){return m.toUpperCase();}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply the internal variable of an anonymous function:

- `m` is the parameter variable with value of `regex`.
- `m.toUpperCase()` is the return value.

Essentially the same as:

```
function toUpperCase(m){
    return m.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case m is just a parameter to a function, so a variable name. You can imagine that function written like this:

```
function toUpperCase(m) {
   return m.toUpperCase();
}
```

Every match found by your regex will be passed to the function as an argument. The variable m will hold that value.